# How can we authenticate our MVC 5 (asp.net) application using OWIN authentication and Drupal account?

Tags: c#, drupal, form-authentication

I want to implement my mvc5 application using Owin/katana concept by Drupal account.If you have any idea related to Drupal authentication using Owin/katana concept then pls reply me step to step. I have only user id and password for Drupal, except this any other information i need for implementation ?